ASP.NET Azure AD / Entra Authentication - App roles in token, but not being assigned to principal
I'm using Azure AD/Entra for OIDC authentication:
    services
        .AddAuthentication()
        .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(
            configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"),
            openIdConnectScheme: "MySchemeName",
            cookieScheme: null,
            displayName: "MySchemeName");

My app registration has an app role defined, and assigned to a user.
On my ChallengeResult callback, I can see the role as a claim in the ExternalLoginInfo object in the Principal.Claims property that is returned from the signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync() method. So clearly the role is correctly in the token.
However, I have a policy defined as:
        options.AddPolicy("MyPolicy", policy =>
        {
            policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
            policy.RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.Role, "AzureAppRoleName");
        });

And when I navigate to a page with this policy defined as [Authorize(Policy = "MyPolicy")] I get a 403.
If I set a breakpoint in some custom middleware, I can see that the HttpContext.User has some claims, but not the role claims.
How do I make sure the role claims returned in the token get assigned to the principal?

See my codes below, when I use mypolicy everything worked well, but if I use [Authorize(Policy = "mypolicy2")] in my Controller action method, I got access denied issue.
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("mypolicy", policy => policy.RequireRole("Tiny.AccessEndpoint"));
    //options.AddPolicy("mypolicy2", policy => policy.RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Tiny.AccessEndpoint"));

});

So that I'm afraid you should change policy.RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.Role to policy.RequireRole

in the access token, what we have is roles claim but  the ClaimTypes.Role points to http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role which might not be what we want.
